# Header in MessageInspector is not being updated

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to implement a message interceptor in various WCF services. My goal is to track every call that is being made between these services since the first call the client made. So I'm trying to attach a counter in the header to know how many services are being called. In my inspector class, in the AfterReceiveRequest method, I check if the header has my property with the counter, if it has it, I add one, and if not I set the value to one.

In this approach I encountered with two problems:
1. In the second call to another service, when AfterReceiveRequest is being called, the property in my header is never there, so is being set there to one again.
2. In the BeforeSendReply I'm trying to update a value in the header, the EndDate with the current date, but that value is neither being returned :-/

I don't know if I'm setting the header wrong. The header in the second call should be the same, right?

This is my inspector class

```
public class LogMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    #region Implementacion de IDispatchMessageInspector

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {            
        try
        {
            LoggerContext lc = new LoggerContext();
            var currentLoggerContext = TryGetHeader<LoggerContext>("LoggerContext", "http://tempuri.org");

            if (currentLoggerContext == null || currentLoggerContext == default(LoggerContext))
            {
                lc.TrackingNo = 1;
                lc.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else
            {
                lc.StartDate = currentLoggerContext.StartDate;
                lc.TrackingNo = lc.TrackingNo + 1;

                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.RemoveAll("LoggerContext", "http://tempuri.org");
            }

            MessageHeader messageHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("LoggerContext", "http://tempuri.org", lc);
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(messageHeader);

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        var currentLoggerContext = TryGetHeader<LoggerContext>("LoggerContext", "http://tempuri.org");
        if (currentLoggerContext != null)
        {
            LoggerContext lc = new LoggerContext();

            lc.EndDate = DateTime.Now;
            lc.TrackingNo = currentLoggerContext.TrackingNo;
            lc.StartDate = currentLoggerContext.StartDate;

            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.RemoveAll("LoggerContext", "http://tempuri.org");
            MessageHeader messageHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("LoggerContext", "http://tempuri.org", lc);
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(messageHeader);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private static T TryGetHeader<T>(string name, string sn)
    {
        try 
        {
            return OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<T>(name, sn);
        }
        catch
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

The LoggerContext is

```
public class LoggerContext 
{
    public int TrackingNo { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; } 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)